# what the following makefile means?

Tags: makefile

Here is Makefile as following, I want to ask what step1 and 2 will do seperately? thanks

```
DIRS = modules utils library

BUILDDIRS = $(DIRS:%=build-%)                           step1

all: $(BUILDDIRS)

$(BUILDDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $(@:build-%=%)                        step2
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dispatching Makefile. Its job is to expose the build targets `build-modules`, `build-utils` and `build-library`. If it is not given any target, it builds the `all` target which depends on all of these.  We can also think about, for instance, `make build-utils` being directly invoked.

Each `build-<whatever>` corresponds to a `<whatever>` dir without the `build-` prefix.

For instance to update the target `build-utils`, the action is to recursively invoke `make` with `-C utils step2` as the arguments: change to the `utils` directory and look for a `Makefile` there, invoking its `step2` target.

This `Makefile` has a flaw: the targets `all` and the `build-<dir>` targets are all phony, but there is no `.PHONY:` declaration for them. This means that `make` will probe the filesystem, looking for files named `all`, and `build-modules`, etc. If you create files with these names, such as by `touch build-modules` or `touch all`, the `Makefile` will then malfunction.